# Framework for administration and distribution of deployments (applications)

Tags: java, deployment, frameworks, administration

Are there any frameworks or tools that help with administration and distribution of developed applications to different physical/logical servers for developement/testing/production?

I am *not* searching for a framework or a tool that is specifically designed for doing builds/deployments (e.g. like Jenkins) as i have different needs e.g. ten thousands of different applications and workflows etc.
What i want is a framework that has the ability of administrating thousands "elements" (which can be applications/sourcecode files etc.) with different attributes that i can use to save some time with a self programmed solution. A java software would be prefered.

I hope that my description somehow makes clear what framework i need. Are there any of these kind available? Commercial software is fine too.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software